# SQL , insert is possible on the table which is not present in terms of hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

does insert query in hibernate requires table to be present. I mean when i have a query that insert some values in to the table which is not present . will the hibernate gives the exception or it will through the exception only when update is done .

I'm speaking in terms of only hibernate .

Can you please suggest

Comment: Logically it should throw exception at the time of insertion itself.

Answer (score 0):

A table being *present in terms of Hibernate* doesn't make much sense in my opinion. A table is present **in the database**, or not. If it is not and if you have an Entity mapped on it, trying to `persist` this Entity will fail at `flush` time, when Hibernate will perform the SQL insert, and you'll get a `HibernateException` wrapping a JDBC exception.

If this doesn't answer the question, please clarify, I did not understand the part where you're referring to an update.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking if the table is missing will Hibernate throw the error or will the database throw the error.

IIRC, I don't think Hibernate will even initialize if the table is missing. You will get an error when its going through the mapping files and trying to pre-generate the CRUD SQL statements based on the datatypes in the database.

Comment: AFAIK, if you want Hibernate to validate the schema against the mappings at initialization time, you have to ask it to do so using `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate`. And I'll check this later but I don't see why Hibernate would use database metadata to generate the CRUD statements (the required informations are in the mappings IMHO). The question is pretty unclear anyway.